# Why SqlConnection is not directly available in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I can use `SqlConnection` in .NET Framework but not in .NET Core framework. Why?

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection_string");
```

I tried this on .NET Core framework and I get an error. But it works fine with .NET framework

Comment: There is .NET-Framework (1.0-4.8), .NET-Core (1.0-3.1) and .NET (5.0-8.0). Something like *.NET-Core Framework* does not exist

Comment: You just need to include the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` assembly in your `using` statements - then `SqlConnection` is available **just fine** on .NET Core / .NET up to v8

Comment: ^^ But mind versions! Microsoft.Data.SqlClient has known vulnerabilities in older versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the .NET Framework by default provides the support for `SqlConnection` class as it is included in the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace, whereas in the .NET Core it's located in the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` NuGet Package. Install the package in your project using the `NuGet Package Manager` and it should remove the error.

Comment: The general gist of this answer is correct but there are some specific inaccuracies. .NET Framework doesn't do anything by default that .NET Core doesn't. It's actually the case that many VS project templates for .NET Framework include a reference to System.Data.dll by default, which is where the `Odbc`, `OleDb` and `SqlClient` providers are defined. There is also a System.Data.SqlClient NuGet package for .NET Core too, although Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is the recommended option.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is poorly formed because you don't really understand how the frameworks are structured or implemented. When you say "directly" in the title of your question, that's just wrong. What you really mean is "by default", but even that's not completely correct.

All .NET frameworks, whether .NET Framework or .NET Core or Mono or whatever, are comprised of assemblies. Those assemblies are .NET DLLs, in which types are defined. .NET Framework is always installed on a system running supported apps, so you always have access to all the standard assemblies. In .NET Core, you can install the framework or the required assemblies can be deployed with each application, or both.

When you create a project in VS, a template is used to generate it. That template will include various things, including certain assemblies being referenced by default. When you create a .NET Framework project, most templates will include a reference to the System.Data.dll assembly. That assembly contains the definitions of types for the ADO.NET providers for ODBC (`System.Data.Odbc`), OLE DB (`System.Data.OleDb`) and SQL Server (`System.Data.SqlClient`). With that reference and an import of the appropriate namespace, you are able to refer to types like `SqlConnection` and to do so unqualified, i.e. without specifying the namespace.

When you create a .NET Core project (.NET 5 and later are based on .NET Core), the same thing happens but the list of included assemblies tends to be smaller and what those assemblies contain may be less too. That's because, if you are going to deploy dependencies along with your application, you want there to be as few as possible and for them to be as small as possible. For this reason, the three ADO.NET providers mentioned earlier are all in different assemblies and it is up to you to install the appropriate NuGet package if and when you need to use one.

When it comes to `SqlClient` in .NET Core, there are two options. There is a System.Data.SqlClient NuGet package that basically contains a .NET Core version of the same provider as you get in .NET Framework. That exists for compatibility. There is also the newer Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package, which started out the same but has since had new functionality added and will continue to do so. Unless you specifically need to use the old version, install the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package, add the appropriate namespace import and write code exactly as you did before, plus enjoy the new functionality if appropriate.